# app.use() requires middleware functions

Tags: express, mean-stack

I am facing this error in my Expressjs file . Here is my code. I tried to set it according to this link
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/169 But I am unable to correct this. Kindly help me out.

```js
/**
 * Express configuration
 */

'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var compression = require('compression');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var path = require('path');
var config = require('./environment');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(app) {
  // var env = app.get('env');
  var env = 'development';

  app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(methodOverride());

  app.use(multer({
    dest: '../client/assets/images/uploads/',
    rename: function(fieldname, filename) {
      return filename + Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function(file) {
      console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting...');
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function(file, req, res) {
      console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to ' + file.path);
      var fileimage = file.name;
      req.middlewareStorage = {
        fileimage: fileimage
      }
    }
  }));

  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(passport.initialize());

  // Persist sessions with mongoStore
  // We need to enable sessions for passport twitter because its an oauth 1.0 strategy
  app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new mongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    })
  }));

  if ('production' === env) {
    app.use(favicon(path.join(config.root, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));
    app.set('appPath', config.root + '/public');
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
  }

  if ('development' === env || 'test' === env) {
    // app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'client')));
    app.set('appPath', 'client');
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(errorHandler()); // Error handler - has to be last
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your multer version as there was a syntax change in how to use multer.

now you have to define something as follows

var upload = multer({.....})

then use upload as your middleware in the express route.

Comment: Thank you . I installed now Multer 1.0.8  . and my problem is fixed . Thank you Avinash

Comment: I will appreciate if you accept the answer and give it a positive vote. Thanks